# forEach context when using loop to modify object literal

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm trying to merge two arrays of objects into one which makes more sense in the application (google maps api v3). I'm getting `obj2 is undefined` error. As far as I understand it is connected to context - I'm calling a function inside forEach loop, and it does not have the access to the objects in the "upper" loop. How can I pass the context or redefine those loops to make it work? `nodes` and `generation` contain lists of objecs. Those objects are simple key-value sets.

```
database = new Array;
function processData(nodes,generation) {


  nodes.forEach(function(value)
  {
     var obj = {
     lat : value.Latitude,
     lng : value.Longitude,
     data : {ID: value.Node, 
            timentries : []}
     }

     currentDate = generation[0].datetime;
     var obj2 =
     {
        time: currentDate,
        technologies :[]
     }

     generation.forEach(function(value2)
     {
        if (value2.datetime == currentDate)
        {
           if (value2.node == obj.data.ID)
              {
                 var obj3 = {
                    type : value2.technology,
                    output : value2["output"],
                    emission : value2["emissions"]
                 }
                 obj2.technologies.push(obj3);
              }
        }
        else
        {
           timentries.push(obj2)
           currentDate = value2.datetime;
           delete obj2;
           var obj2 =
           {
              time: currentDate,
              technologies :[]
           }

        }
     })


  database.push(obj)   
  })
};
$( document ).ready(function() {
    loadData(processData);
});
```

the error occurs in the first reference to obj2:

```
 if (value2.datetime == currentDate)
        {
           if (value2.node == obj.data.ID)
              {
                 var obj3 = {
                    type : value2.technology,
                    output : value2["output"],
                    emission : value2["emissions"]
                 }
                 obj2.technologies.push(obj3);
              }
        }
```

Comment: Sure it has access to the context of the "upper" forEach - JavaScript lets you do that. That's not the problem you're facing.

Comment: if "nodes" and "generation" are Arrays, why not use "for(var n=0;n<nodes.length;n++)" to loop the arrays and avoid both closures altogether. Maybe you can pinpoint the error easily, and you'll improve performance also.

Comment: Well, the object becomes undefined in the generation.forEach(function(value2) {...} loop. Despite the fact "this" value is still the same.

Comment: @LucioM.Tato I know I could (I will try in a second), but I don't understand what is going on here and it is puzzling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, your code is hitting this part:

```
    else
    {
       timentries.push(obj2)
       currentDate = value2.datetime;
       delete obj2;
       var obj2 =
       {
          time: currentDate,
          technologies :[]
       }

    }
```

Note that you're deleting obj2 and re-declaring obj2 in the local scope of the "else" block.  There's no need to delete it (which actually wouldn't have an affect on a variable anyway) and re-declare it.  Instead of those lines, just do:

```
    else
    {
       timentries.push(obj2)
       currentDate = value2.datetime;
       obj2 =
       {
          time: currentDate,
          technologies :[]
       };
    }
```

Comment: Actually I didn't explicitly say it, but the error occurs earlier - I updated the question.

Comment: +1 but should be pointed out that `delete obj2` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @sirVir: It's because your `var` declaration gets hoisted to the top of that inner function, so it's `undefined` before the assignment happens. You should apply this answer as it will fix it, but be aware that you're now overwriting the `obj2` from the outer scope. If you don't want that, then you should be using a different variable name in the inner scope.

Comment: That's what I wanted - I push the value to the array array and prepare another object as a next entry. But why is it `undefined` if I have just defined it?

Comment: @sirVir it's because you're re-defining it in a local context.  When you declare it (with var) under the "else" context in the code above, the variable obj2 is now part of that local scope, and will no longer exist once that local scope ends.  For instance: { var local = 'test'; } alert(local); will be undefined because local is declared in the context of a block.  However var global = 'test'; {global = 'blah'} alert(global); would alert "blah" because the block in the local context is merely assigning a value, not re-declaring the variable called global.

Comment: @DulabCMS `{ var local = 'test'; } alert(local);` alerts `'test'` because in javascript `{}` don't define a scope (except if you use `let` instead of `var`)

Comment: @BlueSkies Thanks, added note to that effect.

Comment: @Oriol Interesting, never realized that.  Thanks for the correction.